# Image Overflows in Asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Forgive me if this question is too silly or asked before. I need to display an Image in my web app and the image is stored in db as byte and I produced the image from the byte but the problem is when I'm displaying it in my web app it over flows means the image frame size is 100x100 but the image comes in its actual resolution. How to solve this my current code is given below

controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ByteToImage()
        {
            ImageDL getImage = new ImageDL();
            byte[] image = getImage.CreateImage();
            return File(image,"Image/jpeg");
        }
```

Razor

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Action("ByteToImage", "User")" height="100" width="100"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the Image in a byte[] format you can re-draw the image to any height width you desire:

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(byte[] imgData, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);

    using (var srcImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
    using (var newImage = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        newImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);//Set your desired image format
        return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below mentioned image tag with height & width mentioned with style rather than declaring independently, that will provide content clipping in all browsers.

```
<img style="width:220px;height:115px;" alt="" src="@Url.Action("ByteToImage", "User")"/>
```